# Grails when to use merge() instead of save()?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, grails

Hello any one suggest me that when to use **merge()** instead of **save()**?

I have some issue like when I save domain with **save()** method it's working fine in some case but in some case it's creating `"org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException"` exception for me.

Can I use direct **merge()** method to save domain instance instead of **save()**?

Answer (score 6):

You can see that both `merge()` and `save()` methods calling `save()` method internally, the difference is in their behavior i.e If you store object in HTTP session and later want to access that but this object has lost its persistent context, the merge() method merge's a detached object's state back into the current Hibernate session.But if you called the save() method on detached object's you will face a sexy exception(`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`) as mentioned by you.
For further info [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html).